# Getting array contents after passing to struct address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Given

```
typedef struct {

    uint32 dataAddress;   

} rsp;
```

an array of data, eg. {1, 2, 3 .... 10}

```
uint8 *msg = NULL;
```

we give the message array to data address

```
rsp->dataAddress = (uint32) msg;
```

How do we print? For example:

```
for (k=0; k < 10; k++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf("Resultant message = %x", (uint8) rsp->dataAddress[k]);
```

Comment: Do you really mean to cast that address to a `uint32`? And if so, why you you declare `dataAddress` as `uint32` rather than `uint8*`?

Comment: You forgot two things: In struct `uint32 *dataAddress; or        uint32 dataAddress[10];` and `rsp->dataAddress = (uint32 *) msg;`

Comment: @valter I don't think any of that is right.

Comment: I see. rsp is not a pointer so it is                       `rsp.dataAddress = (uint32 *) msg;` The printf must be changed accordingly. ps He needs the actuall value of the pointer msg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interpret `dataAddress` as a pointer to an array of `uint8`, then you need to cast. Essentially the cast is the opposite one you made when you assigned `dataAddress`. The cast you already made was from `uint8*` to `uint32`. And so the reverse cast therefore looks like this:

```
(uint8*)rsp->dataAddress
```

To access elements of the array you write:

```
((uint8*)rsp->dataAddress)[k]
```

I do wonder why you elected to declare `dataAddress` as being of type `uint32`. It seems to me that it would be more sensible to declare it to be `uint8*` and thus avoid all the casts.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get something running.
Thank you, everyone. You are great.

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
 uint32_t dataAddress;
} rsp;

#define LEN 10

void main() {

int i = 0;
uint8_t *msg = NULL;

msg = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*LEN);

printf("Init: \n");
for (i=0; i<LEN; i++) {
    msg[i] = i;
    printf("%d ", msg[i]);
}

printf("\n");
printf("Address: 0x%x \n", msg);
printf("Address: 0x%x \n", (uint32_t) msg);

rsp *rsp_ptr;
(rsp_ptr->dataAddress) = (uint32_t) msg;

for (i=0; i < LEN; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf(" %x",  ((uint8_t*) rsp_ptr->dataAddress)[i]);

printf("\n");

}
```